# ListBox Returning To Last Position after Adding Item

Tags: c#

I have small problem with my ListBox. My program is sniffing packets and add description as a header to ListBox and then afterselect all to TextBox. Problem is that incoming packets is about 1-2 per 1s, and when i start scrolling to down refreshed LB getting back me to last selected pos

[URL=[http://pl.tinypic.com/r/nl9yrd/8]View](http://pl.tinypic.com/r/nl9yrd/8%5dView) My Video[/URL]

Comment: So do you mean "You don't want list box to scroll to added item and you want to preserve listbox selection"?

Comment: Please watch the vidio. Problem is that i cant scroll to end select because new added item fast refreshing LB and backing scrollbar to last selected index

Answer (score 0):

Yo can jump to an item by setting `SelectedIndex` if you want to retain your selection before adding an item you can read `SelectedIndex` and set it again;

```
var oldIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex;
listbox.Add("Something");
listbox.SelectedIndex = oldIndex;
```